# Jquery JavaScript create dynamic 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

Hi I see there are loads of examples but none explains what I need done.

I want to create and add items to a 2 Dimensional array and sort dynamically.

Some code I have been messing around with:

```
var Amount = new Array(new Array());  //MULTI ARRAY
var a = 0; //COUNTER

$("input[id^='AmountSpent']").each(function(){
    Amount[a][a] = [a, $(this).val()]; //THIS IS WHERE I GET STUCK... HOW TO ASSIGN VALUES
    a = a + 1;
});
```

After that I want to sort the array.

So if the array looks like this:

```
Amount = [[1,2,3,4],[$200,$300,$100,$600]]
```

I want to sort highest amount first: `$600, $300, $200, $100`

Can anyone please help me.

---

U P D A T E

---

Using the code i got from Rory(*Thanks a lot*) I am doing the following:

```
var amounts = [];    
$("input[id^='AmountSpent']").each(function(i, el){
  amounts.push({ index: i + 1, value: $(el).val() });
});
amounts.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.value < b.value) return 1;
  if(a.value > b.value) return -1;
  return 0;
});
```

To loop through the array I am doing :

```
for (ii = 0; ii < amounts.length; ++ii) {
console.log(amounts[ii].index + " - " +  amounts[ii]); // 
 }
```

The Result I get is :

1 - [object object]
2 - [object object]
3 - [object object]

Comment: If there a specific reason that you need it to be a 2 dimensional array? Why not an array of objects which contains both sets of information?

Comment: What I need to do is I have a value say a = $900 In the array I want to have the sum of the highest values that make up $900 so basically I want to get the indexes/id's [4,3] to use for another calculation.

Answer (score 3):

A multidimensional array is probably overkill for this. Personally I'd use an array of objects - assuming you need to store the index at all.

```
var amounts = [];    
$(".foo").each(function(i, el){
    amounts.push({ index: i + 1, value: $(el).val() });
});

amounts.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.value < b.value) return 1;
    if(a.value > b.value) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GKnUq/2)

---

**Update**

Your loop code doesn't access the `value` property, try this:

```
for (ii = 0; ii < amounts.length; ++ii) {
    console.log(amounts[ii].index + " - " +  amounts[ii].value);
}
```

Comment: THANKS Gonna try it now! You are probably right about the overkill but I am not a hardcore programmer, just came across this problem  in a small project I am doing. What I need to do is I have a value say a = $900 In the array I want to have the sum of the highest values that make up $900 so basically I want to get the indexes/id's [4,3] to use for another calculation.

Comment: When I want to loop through array i get a [object object] error @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @Nev I've updated my answer to show you how to get the value from the loop